# Using RVM via Integrity continuous integration

Tags: ruby, bash, continuous-integration, rvm, integrity

I am currently using Integrity for continuous integration. The CI server is running with 'integrity' gemset, but the application (and it's Rspec test suite) it is supposed to start and test is designed to run with another gemset called, say, 'portal'.

So i use the following build script:

```
rvm use 1.9.2-p290@portal
bundle exec rake spec
```

The output i get is

```
RVM is not a function, blah-blah-blah
```

Basically it says is rvm is not sourced in a not logged in shell. Not a big deal, let's add this to .bashrc:

```
if [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then
  # First try to load from a user install
  source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Cool, now any terminal i launch can call rvm use command without weeping for help. But integrity wouldn't care about that and it still says rvm is not a function.

Hell if i know how Integrity calls system commands, but i'm kidna out of ideas here.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is just one command then run:

```
rvm 1.9.2-p290@portal do bundle exec rake spec
```

For more commands do:

```
source $( rvm 1.9.2-p290@portal do rvm env --path )
bundle install
bundle exec rake spec
```

Comment: Thanks, totally solved my problem. It does something weird with environment, so you have to call {rvm version@gemset do} each time you want to execute something via that gemset.